How to upgrade TigerVNC to 1.12 on Debian 11?
I have a development machine running Debian 11, which is currently our standard environement for equipment hosts. I use VNC (TigerVNC server) to access it remotely from my work computer.
The problem is that TigerVNC that comes with Debian 11 has a very annoying bug, that interferes with my work.
The bug has been long fixed, but there is no official backport and backports for Debian 11 are EOLed to my knowledge.
So the only way to get the fix is to backport TigerVNC manually.
I tried to follow the backporting guide by Faheem Mitha, because it appears to be the most suitable method for this case, which requires Debian-specific configuration and build. I manage to get up to Step 4:
 debuild -uc -us
 dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package tigervnc
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 1.12.0+dfsg-8~bpo11+1
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution bullseye-backports
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by 
 dpkg-source --before-build .
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
dpkg-source: info: using options from tigervnc-1.12.0+dfsg/debian/source/options: --single-debian-patch --create-empty-orig
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: libxft-dev libxcursor-dev libxrandr-dev libxdamage-dev libwrap0-dev xorg-server-source (>= 2:21) xserver-xorg-dev appstream quilt bison flex x11proto-dev (>= 2021.5) libxcvt-dev libxfont-dev (>= 1:2.0.1) libxkbfile-dev (>= 1:0.99.1) libpciaccess-dev (>= 0.12.901) libgcrypt-dev libudev-dev (>= 151-3) libselinux1-dev (>= 2.0.80) libaudit-dev libdrm-dev (>= 2.4.107-5~) mesa-common-dev libunwind-dev libxmuu-dev (>= 1:0.99.1) libxrender-dev (>= 1:0.9.0) libxi-dev (>= 2:1.8) libxpm-dev (>= 1:3.5.3) libxaw7-dev (>= 1:0.99.1) libxmu-dev (>= 1:0.99.1) libxtst-dev (>= 1:0.99.1) libxres-dev (>= 1:0.99.1) libxfixes-dev (>= 1:3.0.0) libxv-dev libxinerama-dev libxshmfence-dev (>= 1.1) libepoxy-dev libegl-dev (>= 1.3.2) libgbm-dev (>= 10.2) libbsd-dev libdbus-1-dev (>= 1.0) libsystemd-dev
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
debuild: fatal error at line 1182:
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui failed

sudo apt-get build-dep tigervnc-standalone-server=1.12.0+dfsg-8
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'tigervnc' as source package instead of 'tigervnc-standalone-server'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:tigervnc : Depends: xorg-server-source (>= 2:21) but 2:1.20.11-1+deb11u14 is to be installed
                      Depends: x11proto-dev (>= 2021.5) but 2020.1-1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libxcvt-dev but it is not installable
                      Depends: libdrm-dev (>= 2.4.107-5~) but 2.4.104-1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libxi-dev (>= 2:1.8) but 2:1.7.10-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

However, I don't understand from the guide what exactly I am supposed to do about unmet dependencies. Am I supposed to lower the required version in debian/control?
And in particular, how do I handle libxcvt-dev that is marked uninstallable?

Apologies for sending you down the backporting rabbit hole — it’s usually the best approach in similar circumstances, but for TigerVNC it turns out to be extremely unhelpful. Backporting the current TigerVNC 12 package to Debian 11 would be rather complex, notably because it’s tied to specific versions of the X.Org packages.
Given the simplicity of the fix for the bug you care about:
diff --git a/common/rfb/VNCServerST.cxx b/common/rfb/VNCServerST.cxx
index fe0608572f..ae51a61b11 100644
--- a/common/rfb/VNCServerST.cxx
+++ b/common/rfb/VNCServerST.cxx
@@ -169,7 +169,7 @@ void VNCServerST::removeSocket(network::Socket* sock) {
       if (pointerClient == *ci)
         pointerClient = NULL;
       if (clipboardClient == *ci)
-        clipboardClient = NULL;
+        handleClipboardAnnounce(*ci, false);
       clipboardRequestors.remove(*ci);
 
       // - Delete the per-Socket resources

it’s much easier to rebuild the Debian 11 TigerVNC package with that patch added in.
To do this:

download the Debian 11 source package of TigerVNC:
apt source tigervnc/oldstable


download the patch:
cd tigervnc-1.11.0+dfsg
curl https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/commit/49122f6dccd836f0a4618247895fd4c5b8db7af0.patch > debian/patches/desktop-clipboard.patch


add it to the list of patches applied to the package:
echo desktop-clipboard.patch >> debian/patches/series


apply it:
quilt push


add a changelog entry:
dch --nmu "Apply upstream fix for clipboard handling."
dch -r ignored


build the package:
debuild -us -uc



